# Python で n個数の平均値を取得したい

Tags: python

Pythonのコードに取り組んでいて、取得したデータから名前、スコア、スコアの最高値、最低値、平均値を求めるコードを書いています。
名前、スコア、スコアの最高値、最低値のプリントするのはできているのですが、平均値を出すコードがうまく書けません。いくつかウェブサイトを見てみたのですが、どれもうまくいきません。以下のコードはモジュールを使ってやってみたやつなんですが、どうもうまくいきません。何か提案等はありますか？

```
from statistics import median
from math import isnan
from itertools import filterfalse

def ScoreList():
    scores = {'name': [], 'score': []}
    while True:
        name = input("Enter a name or enter 'done' when finished ")
        if name == 'done': break
        scores['name'] += [name]
        score = input('Enter score ')
        scores['score'] += [int(score)]

    return scores

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scores = ScoreList()
    print(scores)
    maxScore = max(scores['score'])
    print("max score is:", maxScore)
    minScore = min(scores['score'])
    print("min score is:", minScore)
    midScore = mid(scores['score'])
    print("average score is", midScore)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`statics`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/statistics.html)の[`mean`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)を使うことで平均が取得できます。

`import median`を`import mean`に書き換え、`mid(scores['score'])`を`mean(scores['score'])`に書き換えてください。

**サンプルコード**

```
from statistics import mean

if __name__ == '__main__':
    score = [10, 20, 30]
    print(score)
    print("max score is:", max(score))
    print("min score is:", min(score))
    print("average score is", mean(score))
```

**実行結果**

```
[10, 20, 30]
max score is: 30
min score is: 10
average score is 20
```

**参考資料**

- [Python - リスト平均計算、3つの方法](https://codechacha.com/ja/python-get-average-of-list/#2-statistics%E3%81%AB%E3%82%88%E3%82%8B%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E5%B9%B3%E5%9D%87%E3%81%AE%E8%A8%88%E7%AE%97)